While adding ZXing Library in build.gradle.kts(Module:app), I am getting Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)
While adding ZXing dependency in build.gradle.kts(Module:app), I am getting Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line).
Can anyone please help me in resolving this issue?
My build.gradle.kts(Module:app) file -
 plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinAndroid)
}


dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.0.0'
}


Removed android-studio tag as that tag is for questions/issues related to the Android Studio product. Your question has nothing to do with Android Studio.

You are using Kotlin for your gradle file, not Groovy, so you need to use parentheses and double quotes:
implementation("com.google.zxing:core:3.4.1")
implementation("com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.0.0")

Also, your app seems to use a version catalog, so you shouldn't even do the above and instead migrate the dependencies.
